# Modifying the decimal mark of stat_poly_eq

Tags: r, ggplot2, linear-regression, ggpmisc

I use the `stat_poly_eq` function from the `ggpmisc` package to add the regression equation in my ggplots. It works perfectly. However, I'd like to change the decimal mark of the equation from period to comma, and I can't figure out how to do this. Any suggestions?

```
data(mpg)

ggplot(mpg, aes(y = displ, x = hwy)) +
  geom_point(alpha = 0.5, color = "cadetblue") +
  geom_smooth(method = "lm", se = F, color = "black", size = 0.5) +
  stat_poly_eq(aes(label = paste(after_stat(eq.label),
                                 after_stat(rr.label),
                                 sep = "*plain(\",\")~~")),
               coef.digits = 3)
```

Comment: Try setting `options(OutDec = ",")` before running ggplot.

Comment: It works for the equation, but not for the R-squared... I also would like an alternative that would not change my global options...

Comment: Well, you can always `oldopts = options(...) ; ggplot(...) ... ; options(oldopts)`. But it *is* weird that it does not work for the `R²`.

Comment: Just for completeness. This was a bug in recent versions of 'ggpmisc'. It is now fixed in 'ggpmisc' 0.5.2 now in CRAN.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply swap the periods for commas using `gsub` in the `rr.label`. The `eq.label` is parsed as an expression, so the period needs to be replaced with something like `*paste(',')*` for this to work:

```r
ggplot(mpg, aes(y = displ, x = hwy)) +
  geom_point(alpha = 0.5, color = "cadetblue") +
  geom_smooth(method = "lm", se = F, color = "black", size = 0.5) +
  stat_poly_eq(aes(label = paste(gsub('\\.', "*paste(',')*", 
                                      after_stat(eq.label)),
                                 gsub('\\.', ",", after_stat(rr.label)),
                                 sep = "*plain(\",\")~~")),
               coef.digits = 3, size = 6)
```

[image]

Comment: Great! I had tried gsub but without success.
Your suggestion works perfectly!
Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

```
data(mpg)
library(ggpmisc)

my_formula <- y ~ x
myformat <- "y = %s %s x, R²: %s"

ggplot(mpg, aes(y = displ, x = hwy)) +
  geom_point(alpha = 0.5, color = "cadetblue") +
  geom_smooth(method = "lm", se = F, color = "black", size = 0.5) +
  stat_poly_eq(
    formula = my_formula, output.type = "numeric",
    mapping = aes(
      label = 
        sprintf(
          myformat,
          format(stat(coef.ls)[[1]][[1, "Estimate"]], digits = 3, decimal.mark = ","),
          format(stat(coef.ls)[[1]][[2, "Estimate"]], digits = 2, decimal.mark = ","),
          format(stat(r.squared), digits = 2, decimal.mark = ",")))
  )
```

I have elaborated my answer based on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70315747/r-scientific-notation-in-stat-poly-eq).

I hope this helps you!

Comment: You're welcome, I'm glad to hear it!

Comment: This is a bug. Next version of 'ggpmisc' will obey the "OutDec" R option. I should have thought of this! (I am a native Spanish speaker...)

Comment: It seems that there is not clean way to fix this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23586741/change-decimal-character-in-sprintf

I will most likely have to add to the package the `gsub()` kludge. The root of the problem is that 'ggpmisc' code makes use of `sprintf()`, while `sprintf()` uses the operating system's locale setting.

Answer (score 2):

'ggpmsic' 0.5.2 is now in CRAN. Bug fixed (I hope)
Important: because of the way 'ggplot2' works the option must be set to the desired decimal marker when the plots is rendered (printer or exported to a graphical format). (The option as set when the `gg` object is created or saved to a variable does not affect the object itself.)

```r
library(ggpmisc) # version >= 0.5.2
#> Loading required package: ggpp
#> Loading required package: ggplot2
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'ggpp'
#> The following object is masked from 'package:ggplot2':
#> 
#>     annotate

old.option <- options(OutDec = ",")

ggplot(mpg, aes(y = displ, x = hwy)) +
  geom_point(alpha = 0.5, color = "cadetblue") +
  geom_smooth(method = "lm", se = F, color = "black", linewidth = 0.5) +
  stat_poly_eq(aes(label = paste(after_stat(eq.label),
                                 after_stat(rr.label),
                                 sep = "*plain(\";\")~~")),
               coef.digits = 3)
#> `geom_smooth()` using formula = 'y ~ x'

options(old.option)
```

[image: The plot using the new vesrion of 'ggpmisc']

I also replaced `size` with `linewidth` to avoid a warning from 'ggplot2' 3.4.0, and changed the comma in `sep` to a semicolon as it seems better when the decimal mark is a comma.

<sup>Created on 2022-12-20 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>